# How to convert algebraic data types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I am a bit lost. I have given these different time sets. The first one is our normal time set. The second one is a time set with a time zone difference (not real world relevant, cause I knot there is not a 12:45 time zone). The third one is only True if the time is am. 
I want to be able to sort these times sets. To create a list and sort them. I think I could do this by import Data.List and then use the sort function. It would be easier tho if I converted all of those different time sets into the same time set. Localtime! 
My problem is how do I convert LocaltimeAM into Localtime?

```
data Time = Localtime {hour, minute :: Int}
          | Globaltime {hour, minute, difference :: Int}
          | LocaltimeAM {hour, minute :: Int, am :: Bool} 
          deriving Show

h :: Time -> (Int, Int)
h (Localtime h m) = (h, m)
h (Globaltime h m d) = ((h+d+24) `mod` 24, m)
h (LocaltimeAM h m am) = (h + (if am then 0 else 12), m)
```

Comment: You write a function. What have you tried? What is the meaning and purpose of the function that you've written?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not understanding pattern matching, even if you posted some code using it. 
You should probably read a tutorial -- there should be many of them around the net.

You might convert everything to `Localtime` using some function similar to the one you posted. Here's a skeleton: you will need to fill the blanks.

```
h :: Time -> Time
h (Localtime h m) = Localtime h m
h (Globaltime h m d) = Localtime (...) (...)
h (LocaltimeAM h m am) = Localtime (...) (...)
```